# Imprimir todas las permutas posibles PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Me ocupa lo siguiente:
Poseo este query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM creador";
```

esta tabla `creador` posee 4 columnas

```
columna1   columna2    columna3    columna4
aaaaaa     bbbbbbb     cccccccc    ddddddd
eeeeee     fffffff     null        null
gggggg     null        null        null
```

y requiero crear en PHP un `while` o una `function` que haga todas las combinaciones posibles tomando como resultado **el concatenado de 4 celdas por cada texto resultado** es decir que **siempre tome 1 sola celda de cada columna** ejemplo:

```
TEXTO 1
aaaaaa bbbbbbb cccccccc ddddddd
TEXTO 2
aaaaaa fffffff cccccccc ddddddd
TEXTO 3
eeeeee fffffff cccccccc ddddddd
```

Poseo este PHP

```
<?php
// $texto = concatenar resultados
$query = "SELECT * FROM creador";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query); 
$n = 1; 
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $texto = $rows['TEXTO']; 
    if ($texto != null){
        echo "<p>$n $texto</p>";
        $n ++;
    }
}
?>
```

alguna sugerencia..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por lo que comentas, estás buscando algo así:

```
SELECT CONCAT(columna1,' ',columna2,' ',columna3,' ',columna4)
    TEXTO FROM (
    SELECT columna1 FROM creador
  ) c1, (
    SELECT columna2 FROM creador  
  ) c2, (
    SELECT columna3 FROM creador  
  ) c3, (
    SELECT columna4 FROM creador  
  ) c4;
```

Se trata de un producto cartesiano, que combina todos los registros de una tabla con todos los de otra. Bueno, en realidad son tres, para poder combinar las cuatro tablas.

Aunque en tu pregunta incorporas los tres ingredientes necesarios:

- qué tienes
- qué quieres
- qué has intentando

Sería interesante que la modificaras, añadiendo:

- La estructura de la tabla en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
- El resultado que te gustaría obtener para los registros de prueba que facilites.
- El código que has intentado, tanto en MySQL como en PHP, para saber exactamente hasta dónde necesitas ayuda.

Quedo a la espera de tu modificación para completar la respuesta conforme a tus aportaciones.

Comment: Saludos Sr David, en efecto es lo que requería pero no lo visualizaba, yo intentaba hacer una function que realice una permuta de los resultados de mi query inicial, pero con su ayuda he solucionado asi: `<?php
$query = "SELECT CONCAT(c1,' ',c2,' ',c3,' ',c4) TEXTO FROM ( SELECT c1 FROM creador ) cc1, ( SELECT c2 FROM creador ) cc2, ( SELECT c3 FROM creador ) cc3, ( SELECT c4 FROM creador ) cc4";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$n = 1;
while ($rows =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$texto = $rows['TEXTO'];
if ($texto != null){
echo "<p>$n $texto</p>";
$n ++;
}
}
 ?>` Gracias

Comment: Genial, me alegra que te haya resuelto la situación. Además, veo que ya tenías el PHP controlado. Para dejar la pregunta bien rematada, puedes modificarla añadiendo tu código PHP sin el SQL y así, si alguien la consulta en el futuro, verá que cuadra pregunta con respuesta. :)

Comment: Listo he aplicado la modificacion en mi consulta, gracias y exitos..!